# I cannot close Excel 2016 after executing a xlwings function

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

when I execute a an Xlwings function I can save and close the workbook. But I cannot close Excel 2016 anymore.
Is this a known issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

Here is how I got it to work:

```
import xlwings as xw
wbPath = [WorkbookPath]
wb = xw.Book(wbPath) 
app = xw.apps.active    
wb.save(wbPath)
#wb.close()

app.quit()
```

Note that I commented out the line `wb.close()`. You can skip this step and instead set the app = active Excel instance, save the workbook, and then quit the app.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

You can use `wb.app.quit()` when you want to close Excel and the associated workbook. Assume that `wb` is your workbook. Keep in mind that `wb.app.quit()` does't work if you used `wb.close()` before `wb.app.quit()`. Here's an example:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"
wb = xw.Book(path)
wb.app.quit()
```

But also consider to open and close workbooks by using [`with xw.App() as app`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App) (since version 0.24.3), I can only recommend it:

```
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App() as app:
    wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")

    # Do some stuff e.g.
    wb.sheets[0]["A1"].value = 12345

    wb.save("test.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```

The `with` statement ensures proper acquisition and release of resources. The `with` statement prevents, when an error occurs before closing Excel properly, the problem that Excel stays open and has possibly hidden excel processes left over in the background (because of  `xw.App(visible=False)`, if it is used). The `with` statement has also the advantage that you don't need `app.quit()` anymore, because Excel closes anyway at the end of the with block. But `wb.close()` at the end of the with block is usable (but not necessary) – it achieves that the next time you open Excel, Excel will not display the message that Excel has recovered data that you may want to keep (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/autorecover-functions-in-excel#when-auto-recover-files-are-deleted)).

---

As a side note, I had a situation where `app.quit()` did not work. In this case I used [`app.kill()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/0.11.8/api.html#xlwings.App.kill) instead.

Comment: With xw.App(visible=False), xlwings creates a background process (in my task manager as "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /automation -Embedding). This doesn't always go away with `app.quit()`, but seems to so far with `app.kill()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on mouwsy's answer, I now have this context manager:

```py
class XwApp(xw.App):
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(*args, **kwargs)
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for book in self.books:
            try:
                book.close()
            except: pass
        self.kill()
```

which I use like so:

```py
with XwApp(visible=False) as app:
    app.books.add()
    
    # or
    
    app.books.open('file.xlsx')
    
    # ...
```

and this seems reasonably clean exiting so far. (But pre-opened Excel windows can always mess things up.)

Comment: This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189330/excel-exe-process-keeps-on-running-if-visible-false-after-any-error

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I was unable to find an answer that worked and figured out a solve.  I was able to close the instance of Excel by accessing the api property in xlwings.

```
xl = xw.apps.active.api
xl.Quit()
```

xlwings is just a fancy wrapper around pywin32, you can directly access the pywin32 functions by implementing the api property.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as follow.
I comment that close the workbook you opened or created before.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()

wb.close()
xw.App().quit()
```